# Subtransactions in functions that can commit

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, plpgsql

I read that I can use a `BEGIN-EXCEPTION` block to have a subtransaction in a `FUNCTION` that can be rolled back. But why is it not possible to commit this subtransaction?

How can I circumvent the *"all-or-nothing"* transaction behavior of functions written in **PL/pgSQL**? Is it possible to have the function make commits using subtransactions while the outer transaction could be rolled back?

Comment: Maybe you will be interested at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25428060/4632019

Answer (score 3):

You can't circumvent it at the time of writing (PG 9.3).

Or more precisely, not directly. You can mimic autonomous subtransactions by using [dblink](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html), but be wary that doing so is a can of worms: what's supposed to happen, for instance, if your outer transaction is rolled back?

For background and references to discussions related to the topic on the PG-Hackers list, see:

http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Autonomous_subtransactions

http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20111218082812.GA14355@leggeri.gi.lan