# How many dblink connections can be opened in postgres

Tags: postgresql, dblink

As autonomus transactions are not avaliable in postgres we are using dblink as a workaroud but there is a scenerio which is as

linked from [Does Postgres support nested or autonomous transactions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25425944/postgres-supports-nested-transaction-or-autonomus-transactions-or-not)

```
 select * from dblink_connect('TEST1','host=localhost port=5432 dbname=tyguy user=postgres password=postgres') as t1(text);
```

Then when we use the method

```
SELECT dblink_get_connections();
```

then only one connection is visible that is absolutely correct named as 'TEST1'

but when i open a new pg admin window or a new session then the same is not avaliable as

```
SELECT dblink_get_connections();
```

returns empty. No connection of name **'TEST1'**

I am confused is DBlink is at database level ? or session level .

if it is at session level then how many dblink named connections can be opened in a database.

Comment: the documentation of dblink (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html) states at the end, that ist will operate at session level.

Comment: @ralf.w since there will be many applications using this could we can give a estimate that how many max connection could be made throgh dblink in a database